# Store JSON object as a string and print each value in java

Tags: java, string, list, for-loop

I have a JSON object
`{"name":["123-abc","234-bca","567-yuio"]}`
 with unknown length. I need to store it as a string and split the commas and iterate to print only the value i.e 123-abc should be printed first then 234-bca etc..
-> Input: `{"name":["123-abc","234-bca","567-yuio"]}`
-> Output: `123-abc
234-bca
567-yuio`

Please help me out as I'm new to coding. Thank You

Comment: It's fine that you're new to coding, but you are expected to at least try and post the code as far as you got. We will gladly help you if you come across specific problems.

Comment: What do you mean that you have a "list...of unknown length"? All lists have a length given by their `size` method. Also, why would you map it into a `String` and then into a `String[]` to print it? You can simply iterate over the list and print its elements.

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look

Comment: Are you sure you need "to store it as a string and split the commas"? Like for me you need just to parse JSON and print out content of string's array.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) object;
String input = json.get("name");
//String input = "\"123-abc\",\"234-bca\",\"567-yuio\"";
String[] strArray = input.split(",");
for (String string : strArray)
    System.out.println(string.replace("\"", ""));
```

Here object is where you stored your JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to split the string at the commas and you have to iterate over the split list, using e.g. a for-loop:

```
for (String val : input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).split(",")) {
    System.out.println(val.replace("\"", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to store it as a string, you can actually just pull out that array from the JSON object and iterate over it.

```
JSON obj = new JSONObject(); //Get/store your data however you'd like. I will call it obj
String[] name  = obj.get( "name" );
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) { //Loop through your array and output each part
    System.out.println( name[ i ] );
}
```

If you need to convert the `obj` to a string use can use the `.toString()` function. But the above should be the easiest way to output that data.

Comment: @Sudhanvac I have included a new answer. If you NEED to store it as a string for some reason please let me know but this would be the easiest way to do what you're looking for.